# vector<int> cannot be initialized with an initializer list in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vector

I am using Visual Studio Code on Mac OS X to build and run a very basic vector program. Here is
the code

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    // Demo vector
    vector<int> arr = { 1,2,3,4,55};

    cout<<arr.size()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The below code on running gives following error

> vectors.cpp:8:17: error: non-aggregate type 'vector' cannot be
> initialized with an initializer list
> vector arr = { 1,2,3,4,55};
> ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated.

I also added **"-std=c++11",** in tasks.json, restarted and visual studio code, but the error remains the same. Here is the tasks.json for reference

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json"
        },
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "option": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc-watch"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "tsc: watch - tsconfig.json"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-std=c++11",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

this is the command being built by Visual Studio Code

> cd "/Users/XXX/PROJECTS/Algorithms/" && g++ vectors.cpp -o vectors &&
> "/Users/XXX/PROJECTS/Algorithms/"vectors

Can some one suggest a way to run this program within Visual Studio Code editor?

Thanks!

Comment: It might not be linking to the standard library. Try the flag -stdlib=libc++

Comment: From the picture, I could read a bit of the struck-out line. And I think it still uses g++ and not clang++ as in your tasks file. Could you confirm if that's the case?

Comment: This is the command -- cd "/Users/XXX/PROJECTS/Algorithms/" && g++ vectors.cpp -o vectors &&
> "/Users/XXX/PROJECTS/Algorithms/"vectors

Comment: OT: Please note that the path you are trying to hide is clearly visible at the top of the linked image. More on topic, how are you starting the compilation process, using an extansion like code runner?

Comment: The cause is indeed that you do not use the expected command. The command line should contain `-std=c++11`, while it does not. It looks like VSCode does not use your json file...

Comment: @Bob__ Thank-you, I updated image file. I am using the Run button on the top right to execute the program.

Comment: I am not able to understand how Visual studio code tasks.json works? I added the -std=c++11 but still it does not seem to be working..

Comment: [Getting started with C++ on Linux with VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux): maybe this helps?! Read through the "Build" section.

Answer (score 0):

I still could not use the Visual studio code run button to run the program, so I ended up running via command prompt using below command

> $ g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp

If someone can share their task.json, it will be good to see. Here is mine

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-g++",
            "--std=c++11",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
    }
]
```

}